# How does File.exists() work in JAVA?

Tags: java, file-io

Does File.exists() decide if a file is the same as another by comparing path, name, or by file content?

Comment: I think the javadoc is clear about your first question: _Tests whether the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname exists._ For you second question, read the file bytes and compare them to the bytes of another file.

Comment: `File.exists` does not do any of that - all it tells you is if a file exists or not, without looking at that file's content.

Comment: Since when did `File.exists()` decide if two files are the same **at all**? I'll admit I'm not the world champion at Java, but I would suspect that the function checks whether a file **exists**, not where it is the same as something else.

Comment: It asks the OS, it knows about files.

Comment: @jalf Ha, world champion of Java. I like that. Is that like the [President of Physics](http://xkcd.com/675/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SourceCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/File.java#File.exists%28%29)

```
   public boolean exists() {
             SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
             if (security != null) {
                 security.checkRead(path);
             }
             return ((fs.getBooleanAttributes(this) & FileSystem.BA_EXISTS) != 0);
         }
```

If you look closely all it does is check permissions by calling the filesystem `fs` and of course the `existing` bit :)

Comment: It also checks whether the file exists!!

Comment: Sorry, should have looked up in the Java documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

[From source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/File.java#File.exists%28%29)

> Tests whether the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname exists.
>
> Returns:
>
> true if and only if the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname exists; false otherwise

```
   public boolean More ...exists() {
746         SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
747         if (security != null) {
748             security.checkRead(path);
749         }
750         return ((fs.getBooleanAttributes(this) & FileSystem.BA_EXISTS) != 0);
751     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`File.exists()` decides whether file exists physically or not.
According to [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists)

```
public boolean exists()
Tests whether the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname exists.
```

If you want to know the whether two files are same by path.You should use
`equals()` method of `File` class.According to [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)

Tests this abstract pathname for equality with the given object.  
Returns true if and only if the argument is not null and is an abstract 
pathname that denotes the same file or directory as this abstract pathname.
```